# Correct webservice update technique

Tags: php, synchronization

This is what I am thinking:

On the mobile app I have, the user can complete a number of forms. To get this on to a server, I will:

1. On the mobile app, loop over all of the completed forms. One at a time, use JSON to send that form data to a webservice.
2. PHP Webservice picks up JSON requests, inserts the data into a database.
3. Once data is confirmed to be inserted in the database, the PHP script returns a simple JSON response to acknowledge the data has been received.
4. Mobile app receives this acknowledgement and deletes that local form data. The loop continues to the next form, and the process repeats...

I'm wondering if there are better ways of copying data than the way I outlined above?

Comment: This isn't really a question on syncing, since there isn't any part of the outlined process where either end is concerned with checking that existing data matches on both sides. As for posting to the server, your outline is pretty simple and should work. The alternative might be to send all data at once instead of one by one.

Comment: I considered all-at-once, but some of the form data might be quite large (maybe a base64 representation of a photo for example). So that's why I thought doing it one at a time might be better, to avoid the webservice script potentially timing out.

Comment: I'd go with one-at-a-time to avoid issues like that as well as ensuring that any on-save logic triggers correctly if that logic depends on record earlier in the series. Also, it's probably just a better design, as it allows an individual record save to fail and clearly reflect that point of failure and allows for just that transaction to be rolled back.